# How to consume ASP.NET Web API from a Java ME Application

Tags: xml, web-services, asp.net-web-api, java-me, kxml2

I have created a java ME application (prototype) and now I need to consume my WEB API service from a MIDlet.
First of all, is it possible to consume Web API services from MIDlets?? I have converted my WCF to Web API just so that I can make my J2ME app have access to my services in a more straightforward way. The problem is that I have no idea how to call my web API methods from a MIDlet. Have you ever done anything similar? Do you have any links that you can share??

## EDIT:

I have found how to consume a method from Web API, but still don't know how to turn what I get from the web API into something I can really display on a mobile screen

This is the code I'm using:

```
HttpConnection connection = null;
InputStream is = null;

final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] response = null;

try {
    connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://myminimarket/api/customers/GetCustomers", Connector.READ);
    connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);

    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.1");

    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        is = connection.openInputStream();

        if (is != null) {
            int ch = -1;

            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                bos.write(ch);
            }

            response = bos.toByteArray();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (bos != null) {
            bos.close();            
        }

        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
            is = null;
        }

        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
            connection = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this is an example of the XML I get from GetCustomers:

```
<ArrayOfCustomer xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WSWebAPI.Helpers">
<Customer>
<codigoCli>30</codigoCli>
<direccion>MCDO. SAN MARTIN PSTO. Nº 06</direccion>
<nroID>26626315</nroID>
<nroTelef>365548</nroTelef>
<razonSocial>ABANTO CASTAÑEDA, PAULA</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<codigoCli>61</codigoCli>
<direccion>
JR. SANTA TERESA DE JUORNET MZA. L. LOTE 11 (FRENTE AL QUINDE-COSTADO DE FARMACIA)
</direccion>
<nroID>10414741067</nroID>
<nroTelef/>
<razonSocial>ACUÑA SIFUENTES, ILZE SOLEDAD</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<codigoCli>69</codigoCli>
<direccion>JR. JOSE GALVEZ Nº 478</direccion>
<nroID>15586005</nroID>
<nroTelef/>
<razonSocial>AEDO YANQUI, MARGARITA</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<codigoCli>115</codigoCli>
<direccion>JR. AMALIA PUGA Nº 1008 TELEF. 367878</direccion>
<nroID>10266028356</nroID>
<nroTelef/>
<razonSocial>ALARCON ZEGARRA, EDULFO</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<codigoCli>144</codigoCli>
<direccion>AV. EVITAMIENTO SUR Nº 1514</direccion>
<nroID>10267292588</nroID>
<nroTelef/>
<razonSocial>ALCANTARA GARCIA EDESBITA</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
<Customer>
<codigoCli>194</codigoCli>
<direccion>
JR. 6 DE JULIO MZ. "C" LOTE 7 URB. LUIS ALBERTO SANCHEZ
</direccion>
<nroID>26956665</nroID>
<nroTelef>362648</nroTelef>
<razonSocial>ALVARADO CARDENAS, CONSUELO SOLEDAD</razonSocial>
<tipoPersona>N</tipoPersona>
</Customer>
</ArrayOfCustomer>
```

Now I have also read that I should use kXML2 , but all the info is so confusing , the only good tutorial I have been able to find was [this one](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/kxml/j2me-xml-parser.shtml), the problem is that it uses KXML, which [according to this page](http://www.kxml.org/) is deprecated

Please if any of you have ever used KXML2 I really appreciate you could help me.

P.S. Currently my services return XML , but if you know how to work with json objects in java ME , I could easily return json instead.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please I really need some help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981296/json-parser-for-j2me

Comment: @JigarJoshi OK, it's seems to be what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I can't see any example of how to use this jar.

Comment: you can google for examples

Comment: @JigarJoshi Only one tutorial http://www.java-n-me.com/2010/11/java-me-and-json.html and the article this tutorial is based on, is not there anymore :(

Comment: @JigarJoshi From the code I added to my question, why do they have to turn the stream into an array of bytes?? Wans't this line  `connection.openInputStream();` suppossed to return the whole XML???

Comment: It looks like you got your XML content in byte[] response. Now you need to parse that response. Take a look at this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890222/need-some-help-in-parsing-this-xml-in-j2me-platform

Answer (score 1):

I think most JavaME developers do it simply by calling a website URL, like. e.g.

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/yourwebservice.aspx
```

And then `yourwebservice.aspx` simply returns data.

For highscore system in the games I've worked on, I'd call something like

```
http://www.gamename.com/webservice.php?action=gethighscores
```

And it would output the highscores in plain text, which my MIDlet would then read.

Here are some examples of reading the return values: http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html